# sentence structure "Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie die von allen anderen"

Tags: sentence-structure

I know that from this sentence

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie die von allen anderen

I can separate this sentence as

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht
>
> > My performance was just as bad

and

> allen anderen
>
> > everyone else.

I'm a bit confused by the part

> wie die von

I know *wie* can mean *like* (similar) but I thought *die* was a relative pronoun to *Leistung* and *von* being *of*

i.e.

> My performance was just as bad like that of everyone else
>
> > My performance was just as bad like the performance of everyone else

What is the purpose of *die* and *von*?
Is this the correct interpretation that I have provided?

Comment: Your right, but I'm a little bit puzzled since German is quite close to Englisch here: as= *wie*, die= *that* (backward reference to *Leistung*), von= *of*.

Comment: Your interpretation is absolutely correct. Grammatically "die" is a demonstrative pronoun. One can replace "die" by "diejenige" and "diejenige" is unquestionably a demonstrative pronoun. In fact, I understand "die" as a shortened "diejenige".

Answer (score 2):

*Die* stands for *die Leistung* (as in principle it could be replaced by *diejenige*).
*Von* is a dative preposition (*die Leistung von wem*) which is used in colloquial speech. There are quite a number of people who consider this bad style and would replace it by the genitive (wessen Leistung):

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie die aller anderen.

Comment: I agree with you, as a relative pronoun should start a relative clause and there isn't any here. I edited my answer.

Comment: Here, _die_ ist a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich *"Die"* can theoretically be either a demonstrative pronoun (replace it with *diejenige*) or simply an elision (replace it with *die Leistung*)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate *"wie"* as *"as"* here. The second *"die"* just refers to the first one (not it's not a relative pronoun here) . We could just as easily repeat *Leistung*:

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie **die** von allen anderen
>   (my performance was just as bad as that of everyone else)

could be written as

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie **die Leistung** von allen anderen
>   (my performance was just as bad as the performance of everyone else)

Note: as another poster pointed out using "von" with the dative is considered bad style and the genitive would be preferred

> Meine Leistung war genauso schlecht wie die aller anderen
>   (my performance was just as bad as everyone else's)